# FirebaseUI: Changing redirect URL on sign in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

So I'm using FirebaseUI, I understand that I can use the signInSuccessWithAuthResult callback or the signInSuccessUrl to change the redirect after a successful sign in. However, the effect is after signing in and being redirected to, let's say, Google Sign-In, the browser changes back to the initial login page briefly until the sign-in is complete. Then it redirects to the desired success URL on completion.

I want to achieve the behavior where after redirecting to Google Sign-In, the browser redirects to a splash page of sorts where I can display a loading icon, instead of going back to the login page. And when the sign-in is successful, then the user is directed to their home page.

How can I achieve this behavior while still using FirebaseUI?